# the data fetched from server passed to redux but there are no data in the component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am following course on coursera  facing weird trouble as the although the dishes data fetched but the returned data in the maincomponet are empty array for dishes

this is the code implementation for fetching data in redux

```
    dispatch(dishesLoading(true));

    return fetch(baseUrl + 'dishes')
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.ok) {
          return response;
        } else {
          var error = new Error('Error ' + response.status + ': ' + response.statusText);
          error.response = response;
          throw error;
        }
      },
      error => {
            var errmess = new Error(error.message);
            throw errmess;
      })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(dishes => {
      dispatch(addDishes(dishes));
    })
    .catch(error => dispatch(dishesFailed(error.message)));
}
```

and the dishes data are returned successfully but  the fetchdishes function called

in componentdidmoount returns empty array

here is the code for fetching dishes in maincomponent

```
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({ 
  fetchDishes: () => { dispatch(fetchDishes())}
});


const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      dishes: state.dishes      
    }
  }
class Main extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);  
    }    
    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("this.props.fetchDishes()")
      this.props.fetchDishes();
      this.props.fetchComments();
      this.props.fetchPromos();
    }
     // the rest of the code
```

Comment: Change to `fetchDishes: () => dispatch(fetchDishes())` remove { } since you want to return dispatch(..)